# cakephp 3 prefill user details in textbox

Tags: database, view, pull, cakephp-3.7

I have update profile view and my form is fully working. I need when i load this form it should be pre filled with database values instead of empty. i dont want to use sessions.
I am using cakephp 3.8 version and in update_profile.ctp file i have below code

```
echo $this->Form->control('firstname',['minlength'=>3, 'value'=>'' ]);
echo $this->Form->control('lastname',['minlength'=>3]);
```

Comment: Please show your code for loading the existing user entity, and for creating the form (not the form controls, which you have here already, but the actual `create` call).

Comment: public function updateProfile()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $userId =  $this->Auth->user('id');
        //echo $this->Auth->user('firstname');
        $userData = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       //has post data execution code
            }           
            
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given below is the updated function

```
public function updateProfile() {
     $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
     $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
     $userData = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       //has post data execution code
     }
     //$this->set(compact('user'));
     $this->set(compact('userData'));
 }
```

You had passed "user" variable, you have to pass userData since in this variable u have fetched the user details.
Once this is passed form will get pr-populated.

Answer (score 2):

We can pass data into update_profile.ctp file from controller using
$this->set(compact('Users'));

here users is a table into database which has fields named 'firstname', 'lastname'

Then we can use it in our form like

```
echo $this->Form->control('firstname',['minlength'=>3, 'value'=>'' ]);
echo $this->Form->control('lastname',['minlength'=>3]);
```

Comment: I already have it Anik any other solution?. I dont want to use session.